# Azure Functions with Python flask would like to query multiple parameters in Postman

Tags: python, api, flask, azure-functions, postman

I am using Azure Functions to get data from Azure SQL database, and tried to get value under three conditions.
I will need to input three parameters to extract the rate value, so I will need to make my url dynamic with three paras.

In my **init**.py code, the route for getting the corresponding record:

```
@app.route("/forwardrate/<valuationDate>/<forwardDate>/<tenor>", methods=['GET'])
def get_forward_rate(valuationDate, forwardDate, tenor):
try:
    query = ''

    valuationdate = valuationDate[:2]+'/'+valuationDate[2:4]+'/'+valuationDate[4:]
    forwarddate = forwardDate[:2]+'/'+forwardDate[2:4]+'/'+forwardDate[4:]

    query = "SELECT rate FROM database where [valuationDate] = \'{valuationdate}\' AND [forwardDate] = \'{forwarddate}\' AND [tenor] = {tenor}".format(valuationdate = valuationdate, forwarddate = forwarddate, tenor = tenor)

    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    #logger.info(query)

    if row is None:
        rate = 'No Rate Found!'
    else:
        rate = str(row[0])

    return rate
except:
    logger.error(error_handling())
    return '!ERROR'

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.WsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

And in my function.json file, I set it as:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "/forwardrate/{valuationdate}/{forwarddate}/{tenor}"
      
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

While I tested locally, I can successfully get data with input the paras directly in the url: http://localhost:7071/forwardrate/06302020/06302020/3

After I deployed to the cloud, under my function, I will get url (under Function > Overview):
[https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net//forwardrate/{valuationdate}/{forwarddate}/{tenor}](https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net//forwardrate/%7Bvaluationdate%7D/%7Bforwarddate%7D/%7Btenor%7D)?

or the url (under Function > Code + Test)
[https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/api/forwardrate/{valuationdate}/{forwarddate}/{tenor}](https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net/api/forwardrate/%7Bvaluationdate%7D/%7Bforwarddate%7D/%7Btenor%7D)

I can still get the correct value with:
https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net//forwardrate/06302020/06302020/3

But is there any way I can set these three paras as exactly "parameters" like key-value pair to input, like we request in postman?
I would like to make my url more flexible with inputting parameters as key value, without inputting them as part of my url, but now it will be like (with the & =):
https://apitesting.azurewebsites.net//forwardrate/?valuationdate=06302020&forwarddate=06302020&tenor=3
[image]
which will totally cause error, totally different from my running url, and couldn't get result with this url.

Is there anyway I can make the parameters be input as key-value in my Azure Functions with flask?
Or how can I input the paras in postman to make it as my original format?

I am very new to the API things and also new to Azure platform, I highly appreciate all suggestions, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into Flask `request.args` [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Request.args). Any URL parameters are made available in (essentially) a `dict`. You'd then need to remove them from the URL path.

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/forwardrate")
def get_forward_rate():
    valuationdate = request.args.get('valuationdate', '')
    forwarddate = request.args.get('forwarddate', '')
    tenor = request.args.get('tenor', '')
    ...


curl https://your.domain/forwardrate?valuationdate=1&forwarddate=2&tenor=3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am/should looking for! Thank you so so so much!